# Use add_filter to pass argument to a function

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change "save card" text in a plugin.

The original plugin code is

```
public function save_payment_method_checkbox() {
    printf(
        '<p class="form-row woocommerce-SavedPaymentMethods-saveNew">
            <input id="wc-%1$s-new-payment-method" name="wc-%1$s-new-payment-method" type="checkbox" value="true" style="width:auto;" />
            <label for="wc-%1$s-new-payment-method" style="display:inline;">%2$s</label>
        </p>',
        esc_attr( $this->id ),
        esc_html( apply_filters( 'dokan_stripe_save_to_account_text', __( 'Save payment information to my account for future purchases.', 'dokan' ) ) )
    );
}
```

I have used the following code to change the text.

```
function save_card(){
    echo esc_html('Save my card.');
}
add_filter('dokan_stripe_save_to_account_text','save_card');
```

The code works but outputs the text above **'p'** tag. How can I output the text within **'label'** tag?

In other words I want to pass my filter function to orginial code's second argument.

Answer (score 0):

Just use like this

```
function save_card(){
    return __( 'Save my card.', 'dokan' );
}

add_filter('dokan_stripe_save_to_account_text','save_card');
```